# Error after pressing the button fast when you turn on GPS

Tags: java, android, google-maps

My button when you press - checks if the GPS is on, and when it is ON performs method:

```
GoogleApiClient.connect();
```

and then gets the last known location.

When GPS is off the program asks you to do.

The program works but I found error in it that I do not know how to fix it.

When I turn on the GPS and after about a second I press the button that the program works, but when I turn on the GPS, and after but FAST (i think its less than 1 second) click on the button this program shuts down and get the message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: ru.xxxxx_myapp.MapsActivity cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
```

Comment: This seems like it's probably a threading issue. What you should do is wait until you receive a response from the GoogleApiClient via the `onConnected()` or `onConnectionFailed()` callbacks before connecting/disconnecting from the Google API again. [This](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html#connect()) may be useful.

Comment: You should post `MapsActivity` and the complete stacktrace.

Comment: @Hsenfow : You can write something more about it?

Comment: @tynn : what is it "stacktrace" ?

Comment: That's more or less all calls leading to the error you posted.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it's caused by multiple calls to `GoogleApiClient.connect()` before a previous call has finished connecting.

I'd assume that something similar to this is happening:

1) The 'Connect' button (or whatever the button is called) is pressed.
2) `GoogleApiClient.connect()` is called. This then begins connecting to the API on another thread.
3) Whilst the previous call to `connect()` is still in progress, the 'Connect' button is pressed again.
4) `GoogleApiClient.connect()` is called again, and so begins the connection process again, resulting in the GoogleApiClient getting confused and throwing an exception.

Although I can't say for sure *why* you're getting a `ClassCastException`, I'd say it's pretty likely this is the cause of the problem.

So, to resolve this problem, in your button event handling code (the place where you call `GoogleApiClient.connect()`), you'll need to do a check to find out whether the client is currently connecting or connected, and if so, then to **not** try connecting again until the client has disconnected.

You'll want something similar to this for your button event handling code:

```
public void onClick(){
    // If the client is not trying to connect and is not currently connected,
    // then start connecting
    if(!GoogleApiClient.isConnecting() && !GoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
        GoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I swapped the `GoogleApiClient.connect()` on a

```
if(!GoogleApiClient.isConnecting() && !GoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
        GoogleApiClient.connect();
```

and still have this same error :(

In the method `public void onConnected(Bundle bundle)`
i have :

```
 if (location == null)
{
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(GoogleApiClient, LocationRequest, (LocationListener) this);
}
```

maybe there is something wrong ? 
I think this would work if the method executed with a delay, but i dont know how to do it.

I think so, because when swapped:

```
 if (location == null)
{
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(GoogleApiClient, LocationRequest, (LocationListener) this);
}
```

on a

```
     if (location == null)
    {
makeMyScreenBlue();
 LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(GoogleApiClient, LocationRequest, (LocationListener) this);
    }
```

and i test it with this "fast click" turn on GPS in my phone and fast after click the button which `GoogleApiClient.connect();` My phone displays a blue screen and next crash with this same error